# Add a column with a value computed from other columns in SQL without using the default value

Tags: sql, t-sql, constraints, default, calculated-columns

I can add a column this way:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ADD MyColumn BIT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT MyConstraint
DEFAULT 0
```

Now, instead of the constant `0` I want to put a different value depending on my other columns in the `MyTable`. I.e. it is a one time computation during the column addition. How could I do that?

Also, I do not want my column to have a default value.

E.g. I have another `BIT` column called `MyOldColumn` and I want to just copy its value into the `MyColumn`.

Comment: Are you talking about a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16)? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @Larnu, `I.e. it is a one time computation during the column addition.`.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of questions in the above comment.

Comment: It sounds like you want to add a column and then `update` the value based on another column as a one-time event. After that you will manage the new column as needed. Is there a problem with doing an `alter table` and an `update` to add and initialize the new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just want to add the column, then run an update using some calculation.

```sql
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyColumn BIT;

UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = SomeCalculation;

ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn BIT NOT NULL;
```

Why set the column to `null` first then `not null`? Because it will be more performant. Setting it to `null` first means it's a meta-data only operation, and will not change the data pages. The final `ALTER` will also not change any pages (although it will read them all), because none of them are null.

Whereas if you set it to `not null` first then all pages get changed, and then changed again.